# How do I restore the default theme for the login screen after rebooting? Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: themes

I'm quite new to Ubuntu and Linux in general, so sorry for the somewhat n00b question...

I've been playing around with different themes using Tweaks. After messing around with a few, I decided to revert back to the Ubuntu default theme. Everything is back to normal, except for when I re-boot, the login screen is still one of the custom themes (One called "Pop" I think) I've deleted all the themes in the themes folder, used the "Reset to Defaults" option in Tweaks, but nothing seems to be working.

Any advice on how to restore to the default login screen theme would be much appreciated :)

I know it's a small thing, but it's annoying the hell out of me...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The appearance of the login-screen is controlled system wide, and not on a per-user base. It is unclear how you could have changed that with Gnome Tweaks alone. Anyway, execute the following command

`sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css`

and select the option `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` to theme your login screen with the default color scheme of Ubuntu.

Comment: This resolved my issue- Thanks! I'm still unsure how I managed to change it through Gnome Tweaks alone. I'm going to assume I did the above at some point (as the offending login theme was in the list I got from the above) and have just somehow forgotten about it....